# Spicing Up Native Circular Plot Using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

**CODE UPDATED**

I have some angle data from an animal behavior study that I would like to plot for publication using ggplot2. What follows is my current workflow with some example data and how it would look using the generic plot function.

```
### Create two data frames of random Cartesian coordinates ###
df1 <- data.frame(
x = sample(10, 11, replace = TRUE),
y = sample(10, 11, replace = TRUE))

df2 <- data.frame(
x = sample(10, 11, replace = TRUE),
y = sample(10, 11, replace = TRUE))

### Write a function that converts continuous Cartesian coordinates to velocities ###
get.polar <- function(df)
{
x <- diff(df$x)
y <- diff(df$y)
d <- complex(real = x, imaginary = y)
steps <- data.frame(speed = Mod(d), angle = Arg(d))
steps[-1,] # Deletes the first row as it does not contain an angle measurement
steps$time <- (1:nrow(steps))/30 # generates a time column in seconds (1 data point = 1/30 of a second)
return(steps)
}

df1_polar <- get.polar(df1)
df2_polar <- get.polar(df2)

require(circular)

### Convert angles into an object of type 'circular' ###
df1_rad <- circular(df1_polar$angle, type = 'angles', units = 'radians', zero=0, rotation = "counter")
df2_rad <- circular(df2_polar$angle, type = 'angles', units = 'radians', zero=0, rotation = "counter")

### Convert radians to degrees with a clockwise rotation and zero at "north" ###
df1_deg <- conversion.circular(df1_rad, type = "angles", units = "degrees", zero = pi/2, rotation = "clock")
df2_deg <- conversion.circular(df2_rad, type = "angles", units = "degrees", zero = pi/2, rotation = "clock")

### Convert negative rotations to positive ###
df1_deg[df1_deg < 0] <- df1_deg[df1_deg < 0] + 360 
df2_deg[df2_deg < 0] <- df2_deg[df2_deg < 0] + 360

par(pty = "s")
plot(df1_deg, units = "degrees")
ticks.circular(circular(seq(0,(11/6)*pi, pi/6)), zero = pi/2, rotation = "clock", tcl = 0.075)
points(df2_deg, zero = pi/2, rotation = "clock", pch = 16, col = "darkgrey", next.points = -0.2)

# Suggested solution by MLavoie with modifications
temp1 <- data.frame(Exercise = c(1, 1, 1, 1), Name = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    Score = c(90, 180, 270, 360))
temp2 <- data.frame(Name=c(replicate(length(df1_deg), 3)),
    Score = c(df1_deg))
temp3 <- data.frame(Name=c(replicate(length(df2_deg), 4)),
    Score = c(df2_deg))
temp4 <- data.frame(Name=c(4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8),
    Score = c(0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315))

ggplot() +
geom_bar(data = temp1, aes(x = factor(Name), y = Score, fill =  factor(Exercise)),
    width = 1, stat = 'identity') + 
geom_point(data = temp2, aes(x = Name, y = Score),
    color = "green", size = 2) +
geom_point(data = temp3, aes(x = Name, y = Score),
    color = "red", size = 2) +
geom_point(data = temp4, aes(x = Name, y = Score),
    color = "black", shape = 8, size = 2) +
geom_vline(xintercept = 4.8) +
annotate("text", x = 0, y = 0, label = "+", size = 6) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315)) +
coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) + 
theme_bw() + ylab("") + xlab("") + 
theme(panel.border   = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    strip.text       = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y      = element_blank(),
    legend.position  = "none", 
    axis.ticks       = element_blank()) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("transparent", "transparent", "transparent", "transparent"))
```

[image: Less than optimal...]

Some suggestions for turning this rough plot into something publishable using ggplot2?

Thank you!
[image: Much better!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this for a start:

```
temp <- data.frame(Exercise=c(1, 1, 1, 1), Name=c(1, 2, 3, 4), Score=c(90, 180, 270, 360))
temp2 <- data.frame(Name=c(2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8), Score=c(90, 180, 270, 360))
temp3 <- data.frame(Name=c(4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2), Score=c(90, 180, 270, 360))
temp4 <- data.frame(Name=c(0), Score=c(180))
temp5 <- data.frame(Name=c(4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8), Score=c(45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 305, 360))

ggplot() +
geom_bar(data=temp, aes(x = factor(Name), y=Score, fill = factor(Exercise)), width = 1, stat='identity') + 
geom_point(data=temp2, aes(x=Name, y=Score), color="grey") + 
coord_polar(theta = "y", start=0) + 
theme_bw() + ylab("") + xlab("") + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(90, 180, 270, 360)) +
theme(panel.border=element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
strip.text=element_blank(),
strip.background=element_blank(),
axis.text.y=element_blank(),
legend.position="none", 
axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("transparent", "transparent", "transparent", "transparent")) + 
geom_vline(xintercept=4.8) +  
geom_point(data=temp4, aes(x=Name, y=Score), color="black", shape=3, size=4) +  
geom_point(data=temp3, aes(x=Name, y=Score), color="black") +
geom_point(data=temp5, aes(x=Name, y=Score), color="black", shape=3, size=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That is certainly a much sharper looking graph. Is there a way to graph two sets of angle data as described in my OP?

Comment: you have two sets, one black, one grey. Just play with data frames temp3 and temp4 and you will the points moving. If you want to keep the black points as ticks for the 4 angles, just make-up a new data frame and add the new data frame with an additional geom_point()

Comment: see edits and new image, 2 sets of points

Comment: Splendid! See the revised code and new image...